# SQL Server - Convert varchar to another collation (code page) to fix character encoding

Tags: sql-server, character-encoding, collation

I'm querying a SQL Server database that uses the SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2 collation.  One of the table rows has a varchar with a value that includes the +/- character (decimal code 177 in the Windows-1252 codepage).

When I query the table directly in SQL Server Management Studio, I get a gibberish character instead of the +/- character in this row. When I use this table as the source in an SSIS package, the destination table (which uses the typical SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation), ends up with the correct +/- character.

I now have to build a mechanism that directly queries the source table without SSIS. How do I do this in a way that I get the correct character instead of gibberish? My guess would be that I would need to convert/cast the column to the SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation but that isn't working as I keep getting a gibberish character.

I've tried the following with no luck:

```
select 
columnName collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
from tableName

select 
cast (columnName as varchar(100)) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
from tableName

select 
convert (varchar, columnName) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
from tableName
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 17):

Character set conversion is done **implicitly** on the database connection level. You can force automatic conversion off in the ODBC or ADODB connection string with the parameter "Auto Translate=False". This is NOT recommended.
See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx

There has been a codepage incompatibility in SQL Server 2005 when Database and Client codepage did not match.
https://support.microsoft.com/kb/KbView/904803

SQL-Management Console 2008 and upwards is a UNICODE application. All values entered or requested are interpreted as such on the application level. Conversation to and from the column collation is done implicitly. You can verify this with:

```
SELECT CAST(N'±' as varbinary(10)) AS Result
```

This will return `0xB100` which is the Unicode character U+00B1 (as entered in the Management Console window). You **cannot** turn off "Auto Translate" for Management Studio.

If you specify a different collation in the select, you eventually end up in a double conversion (with possible data loss) as long as "Auto Translate" is still active. The original character is first transformed to the new collation during the select, which in turn gets "Auto Translated" to the "proper" application codepage. That's why your various COLLATION tests still show all the same result.

You can verify that specifying the collation DOES have an effect in the select, if you cast the result as `VARBINARY` instead of `VARCHAR` so the SQL Server transformation is not invalidated by the client before it is presented:

```
SELECT cast(columnName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2 as varbinary(10)) from tableName
SELECT cast(columnName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as varbinary(10)) from tableName
```

This will get you `0xF1` or `0xB1` respectively if `columnName` contains just the character '±'

You still might get the correct result and yet a wrong character, if the font you are using does not provide the proper glyph.

Please double check the actual internal representation of your character by casting the query to `VARBINARY` on a proper sample and verify whether this code indeed corresponds to the defined database collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2`

```
SELECT CAST(columnName as varbinary(10)) from tableName
```

Differences in application collation and database collation might go unnoticed as long as the conversion is always done the same way in and out. Troubles emerge as soon as you add a client with a different collation. Then you might find that the internal conversion is unable to match the characters correctly.

All that said, you should keep in mind that Management Studio usually is not the final reference when interpreting result sets. Even if it looks gibberish in MS, it still might be the correct output. The question is whether the records show up correctly in your applications.

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Must be used convert, not cast:

```
SELECT
 CONVERT(varchar(50), N'æøåáäĺćçčéđńőöřůýţžš')
 COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI
```

(http://blog.sqlpositive.com/2010/03/using-convert-with-collate-to-strip-accents-from-unicode-strings/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

We may need more information. Here is what I did to reproduce on SQL Server 2008:

```
CREATE DATABASE [Test] ON  PRIMARY 
    ( 
    NAME = N'Test'
    , FILENAME = N'...Test.mdf' 
    , SIZE = 3072KB 
    , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB 
    )
    LOG ON 
    ( 
    NAME = N'Test_log'
    , FILENAME = N'...Test_log.ldf' 
    , SIZE = 1024KB 
    , FILEGROWTH = 10%
    )
    COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
    (
    [SomeCol] [varchar](50) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
Insert MyTable( SomeCol )
Select '±' Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
GO
Select SomeCol, SomeCol Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
From MyTable
```

Results show the original character. Declaring collation in the query should return the proper character from SQL Server's perspective however it may be the case that the presentation layer is then converting to something yet different like UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
SELECT CAST( CAST([field] AS VARBINARY) AS varchar)
```

Comment: This worked for me. Bu also I need to add that programmer should indicate lenghts like (VARBINARY(120)) ... VARCHAR(120). If not it cuts the output.

Answer (score 1):

I think
SELECT CAST( CAST([field] AS VARBINARY(120)) AS varchar(120))
for your update